# C# adding negative values to chart

Tags: c#, charts, addition

Can anybody help me, why I can't add negative values to the chart (windows form)? the part of code is below:

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(a, Convert.ToDouble(rx_str_copy));
```

for example as input:    **rx_str_copy = "-128.00"**

It throws a communicate that input string is wrong. 
With positive values I don't have any problems

What is wrong?

I'm updating my question:

So far I've tried to add values without dot, so it was just like integer covered in string and then converted to double.
Now I'm trying to add values with dot so now it's double covered in string and then convert to double.

I realized problem with negative and positive  values also. So the problem lies with dot in string. 
Can anybody help with that?

Comment: What "chart"?  What are you talking about??

Comment: Sorry, I mean Line chart

Comment: As mentioned, Windows form

Comment: Could you post a bit more context? I just simulated this and it worked for me completely as expected.

Comment: I've just updated my question

Comment: How can you have a negative value? If I have two oranges, I have an orange and another orange (not the *same* orange, mind you). If I have negative two oranges, what do I have, Cherenkov radiation? The whole concept makes no sense and it's high time we stopped pretending.

Comment: @Ed, funny, but confusing OP is not really called for.

Comment: Maybe the minus sign is wrong or maybe the dot should be a comma? Culture??

Comment: I stand by my answer, you could insert any values into `addxy()`, but I cannot simulate your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple test case like this works perfectly for me. For your case, is `a` a double already?

```
public Form1 ()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void chart1_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    string rx_str_copy = "-128.00";
    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(-1.00, Convert.ToDouble(rx_str_copy));
}
```

Comment: a is integer. This chart control can get points as an integer also